# How to mount a drive from terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, mount

I want to mount a drive from terminal at startup. At startup if I use `ls /media`, I notice that it is empty. If I go to *Computer* and click on VM drive there, I can then see the VM driver in `ls /media`.

How can I mount that drive from the terminal without having to go to *Computer*? Something like

```
mount VM
```

Or how can find the path of VM like `/dev/sda` or something?

Comment: If someone is looking for how to mount **managed azure disk** to Ubuntu VM: check this azure doc [attach a data disk to a Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal?tabs=ubuntu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `pmount`, from the [manual page](http://man.cx/pmount):

```
 pmount  ("policy mount") is a wrapper around the standard mount program
 which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a  match-
 ing /etc/fstab entry.

 pmount is invoked like this:

 pmount device [ label ]

 This  will  mount  device  to a directory below /media if policy is met
 (see below). If label is given, the mount point will  be  /media/label,
 otherwise it will be /media/device.
```

Answer (score 30):

Remember you've to make a directory first like this:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Name_of_directory
```

The above command will create a directory (folder) in media folder by replacing "Name_of_directory" with your providing folder name.

You can see drives numbers or id by:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then mount the drive through:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda# /media/Name_of_directory
```

Where # must be replaced with legal number associated with your drives in Ubuntu (Linux Distro)

If you see this error:

> mount: /media/sci: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/vdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

It means you still need to create a (new) file system.  (Double-check that you really want to overwrite the current content of the specified partition! Replace `X#` accordingly, but double check that you are specifying the correct partition, e.g., sda2, sdb1):

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX#
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a summary of the following [guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-properly-automount-a-drive-in-ubuntu-linux/) which worked for me.

To automatically mount the drive in Ubuntu (without installing another package) you need to update `/etc/fstab`

First create a mount point, e.g.

```
sudo mkdir /data
```

Then get the Universal Unique ID for the device

```
sudo blkid
```

Then update fstab

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Adding a line like this at the bottom of the file

```
UUID=14D82C19D82BF81E /data    auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

where

- `UUID=14D82C19D82BF81E` is the UUID of the drive. You don't have to use the UUID here. You could just use /dev/sdj, but it's always safer to use the UUID as that will never change (whereas the device name could).
- `/data` is the mount point for the device.
- `auto`  automatically mounts the partition at boot
- `nosuid` specifies that the filesystem cannot contain set userid files. This prevents root escalation and other security issues.
- `nodev` specifies that the filesystem cannot contain special devices (to prevent access to random device hardware).
- `nofail` removes the errorcheck.
- `x-gvfs-show` show the mount option in the file manager. If this is on a GUI-less server, this option won't be necessary.
- `0` determines which filesystems need to be dumped (0 is the default).
- `0` determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time (0 is the default).

Answer (score 3):

You can run `fdisk -l` to show you all the disk devices, or after mounting it in the GUI, drop down to the Terminal and run `cat /proc/mounts` and find your device that's mounted.  You can then copy/paste that line from `cat /proc/mounts` into `/etc/fstab` and it'll be mounted at startup.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't bother to install pmount you could first check the name of your partition with

```
lsblk
```

Then, assuming you find it on /dev/sdb1 you could do

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ -o uid=1000,gid=1000,rw
```

assuming that you are user 1000. The uid and gid gives you permission to read and write (rw) on the mount, otherwise only root will have read and write access. Obviously you can add more options in -o (see man mount).

You can check your uid and gid with

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep YourUserName
```

Cheers, 
hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`devkit-disks` will let you query and mount devices, with the `--enumerate-device-files` and `--mount` options respectively.